# Python - Log stacktrace while Jinja2 rendering

Tags: python-2.7, stack-trace, jinja2

The following codes

```
import jinja2

class SomeObj(object):
    def call(self):
        x = dict()
        x['raise']

template = jinja2.Template('{{ obj.call() }}')
template.render(obj=SomeObj())
```

would cause Jinja2 crashed and print the following info to console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in 
    template.render(obj=SomeObj())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "", line 1, in top-level template code
  File "test.py", line 6, in call
    x['raise']
KeyError: 'raise'
```

It contains call trace since the `render` function. But when I try tracking it in this way

```
class SomeObj(object):
    def call(self):
        try:
            x = dict()
            x['raise']
        except KeyError:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()

template = jinja2.Template('{{ obj.call() }}')
template.render(obj=SomeObj())
```

I got only

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in call
    x['raise']
KeyError: 'raise'
```

What's the proper way to get the full stacktrace in Jinja2 rendering context? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you wanting to get the first traceback as text or something? In the second traceback, there is no stack to unwind, since you've caught the exception right where it happens.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, in one word, I'd like to get the former traceback in the `call` function.

Comment: Hmm, maybe call `traceback.print_stack()` rather (or in addition to) than `print_exec()`? The stack will be the functions that are still running (up to the application's top level, unless you specify a limit), while the exception's traceback will show what has been unwound already.